# TombstoneOverwhelmingException in Cassandra

Tags: exception, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, tombstone

So I'm getting this exception when querying the data from a table. I read a lot online and from what i understand, this happens because i have a lot of null rows. But what's a way to solve this? Can I just easily get rid of all these nulls?

UPDATE:
I ran `nodetool compact` and also tried scrubing.  In both cases I get this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/bitcoin/okcoin_order_book_btc_usd/bitcoin-okcoin_order_book_btc_usd-jb-538-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/bitcoin/okcoin_order_book_btc_usd/bitcoin-okcoin_order_book_btc_usd-jb-710-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/bitcoin/okcoin_order_book_btc_usd/bitcoin-okcoin_order_book_btc_usd-jb-627-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/bitcoin/okcoin_order_book_btc_usd/bitcoin-okcoin_order_book_btc_usd-jb-437-Data.db')]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$13.call(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2132)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$13.call(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2129)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2111)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.markAllCompacting(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2142)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getMaximalTask(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:254)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.submitMaximal(CompactionManager.java:290)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performMaximal(CompactionManager.java:282)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.forceMajorCompaction(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1941)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.forceKeyspaceCompaction(StorageService.java:2182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And these are  the last lines from  `system.log`

```
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:22:54,272 CompactionController.java (line 192) Compacting large row bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny:1972-05 (225021398 bytes) incrementally
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:07,528 CompactionController.java (line 192) Compacting large row bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny:1972-06 (217772702 bytes) incrementally
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:20,508 CompactionController.java (line 192) Compacting large row bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny:2014-05 (121911398 bytes) incrementally
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-01-03 07:23:30,941 GCInspector.java (line 116) GC for ParNew: 223 ms for 1 collections, 5642103584 used; max is 8375238656
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:33,436 CompactionController.java (line 192) Compacting large row bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny:2014-07 (106408526 bytes) incrementally
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:38,787 CompactionController.java (line 192) Compacting large row bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny:2014-02 (112031822 bytes) incrementally
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:46,055 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 794) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-compactions_in_progress@582986122(0/0 serialized/live bytes, 1 ops)
INFO [FlushWriter:62] 2015-01-03 07:23:46,055 Memtable.java (line 355) Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@582986122(0/0 serialized/live bytes, 1 ops)
INFO [FlushWriter:62] 2015-01-03 07:23:46,268 Memtable.java (line 395) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compactions_in_progress/system-compactions_in_progress-jb-22-Data.db (42 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1420135510457, position=14938165)
INFO [CompactionExecutor:1888] 2015-01-03 07:23:46,354 CompactionTask.java (line 287) Compacted 2 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/bitcoin/okcoin_trade_btc_cny/bitcoin-okcoin_trade_btc_cny-jb-554,].  881,267,752 bytes to 881,266,793 (~99% of original) in 162,878ms = 5.159945MB/s.  24 total partitions merged to 23.  Partition merge counts were {1:22, 2:1, }
WARN [RMI TCP Connection(39)-128.31.5.27] 2015-01-03 07:24:46,452 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 2103) Unable to cancel in-progress compactions for okcoin_order_book_btc_usd.  Probably there is an unusually large row in progress somewhere.  It is also possible that buggy code left some sstables compacting after it was done with them
```

I'm not sure what the last line means. There seem to not be extremely large rows (i don't know how to find if there are any). As a note there is still that compaction stuck at 60.33% and it's stuck at `okcoin_order_book_btc_usd`.
I'm running Cassandra 2.0.11

Comment: An `AssertionError` indicates a bug. If that is the Cassandra log file, it indicates a bug in Cassandra.

Comment: Good catch on the AssertionErrors.  Just curious, is that what comes out from nodetool compact, or was that what was in the system.log file?  I would hope the system.log file has a stack trace, if you can capture that and put it on a pastie that would be good to have since this is likely a cassandra bug.  Also, what version of 2.0?  Are you on 2.0.11?

Comment: Looks like someone hit this same issue rather recently as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8548, but the root cause isn't understood yet.  I linked this post to that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Tombstones are created when you delete rows or when they are expired from Cassandra.  They will be removed on compaction of SSTables after gc_grace_seconds elapses for that row.

There are a few things I can think of to help alleviate the number of tombstones:

1. Set a lower gc_grace_seconds for the table that has a lot of tombstones - gc_grace_seconds should typically be 1 day greater than how often you are doing repairs.  If you are doing repairs more often than this, you could consider lowering gc_grace_seconds.
2. Take a look at how your compactions are going.  Do you have a lot of pending compactions?  (nodetool -h localhost compactionstats on each node will show this).  It's possible you are getting behind on compactions and data isn't getting cleaned up as soon as it should be.  It may also be worth considering changing your Compaction Strategy if appropriate.  For example, if you are using SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, it may be worth looking into LeveledCompactionStrategy, this strategy typically causes more compaction activity (so make sure you have SSDs), which could get your tombstones cleaned up faster.
3. Take a look at your data model and the queries you are making.  Are you frequently deleting or have expired data in a partition that you are reading from frequently?  Consider changing your partitioning (primary key) strategy so it is less likely for deleted or expired rows to be in your 'live' data.   A good example of this add time/date to your primary key.
4. Tweak tombstone_failure_threshold in cassandra.yaml - Probably would not consider doing this as this is a good indication you need to look at your data.

Comment: thanks a lot! when i looked at compaction stats, there is pending compaction that seems to be at 60.33% for about an hour now. Is this normal?

Comment: That could indicate a very wide partition, which I suspect could be the case in your situation since you have a lot of tombstones when doing reads.

Do you think it's possible that you have some really wide partitions?  (Partition key with a lot of rows)

Also, are there any pending tasks or is it sitting at 0?

If you have the monitoring capability in place, I would set up monitoring for pending compactions and total bytes compacted, you can find those statistics in JMX.  [Good talk on cassandra monitoring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhUoQPHNA1Y).

Comment: Oh, should add since you asked.  It's not too unusual, but 1 hour is a long time, i'd keep an eye on it.

Comment: so it says pending tasks: 1; and there is still that compaction stuck at 60.33% What do i do?

Comment: Not good!  Any interesting exceptions in the system.log file?  Also, could you check for instances of 'Compacting Large Row' in the system.log file?  Would be interesting to see if you have any of those and how big the reported rows are.  I've seen them super huge before (upwards of 70GB...happens when you make mistakes in data modeling :)), but not take nearly that long, maybe an hour or two.  Also, try doing a 'nodetool cfstats <keyspace_name>.<table_name>' and see what the value of 'Compacted partition maximum bytes' (name may be different depending on cassandra version, to get a good idea.

Comment: Also, what version of cassandra are you using?  Maybe there is some known issue that we can track down, or perhaps this is some kind of bug.